# Does this condition imply a polynomial is a product of linear factors

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, group-cohomology

Let $\Lambda$ be a lattice (i.e. $\Lambda \simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$) with a positive subcone $\Lambda^+$. Let $H: \Lambda^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a function such that $\forall\mu \in \Lambda^+$, $b_\mu(\lambda) := \frac{H(\lambda + \mu)}{H(\lambda)}$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$. To put it another way, let $b: \Lambda \rightarrow Rat(\Lambda)$ be a cocycle (in the group cohomology complex with $Rat(\Lambda)$ being rational functions on $\mathbb{C}\Lambda$ and the translation action) such that any element of the positive subcone is a polynomial. I think, but haven't figured out how to prove, the following:

$$b_\mu ~~\text{factors as}~~ b_\mu = \prod_i (\alpha_i + k_i), ~~\text{where}~~ \alpha_i \in \text{Hom}(\Lambda, \mathbb{C})$$

In fact, I have a bigger conjecture:

$H(\lambda)$ is a product of factorials of linear factors (i.e. factors of the form $\alpha_i + k_i$ with $\alpha_i \in \text{Hom}(\Lambda, \mathbb{Z})$ multiplied by an exponential function multiplied by a product of linear factors.)

A few examples: The most basic examples are products of factorials of linear factors; however, we can also consider the case $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z}, H(\lambda) = (3 \lambda)! (3 \lambda + 2)$.

I wasn't quite sure what to tag this with, so please feel free to tag it appropriately.

Comment: I don't quite get it. You have a multivariate (if $\operatorname{rank}\Lambda>1$) polynomial; why should it split into linear factors?

Comment: Also, what if   $H(\lambda):=\prod_{j=1}^\lambda (j^2+1)$, for $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ ?

Comment: Is this related to the Weyl dimension formula? 
That is, in the end of properties on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial#Properties
? This formula is essentially a lattice point counting number.

Comment: Alex: I don't just have one polynomial, I have many with a certain compatibility condition; I think that that compatibility condition implies factoring.

Comment: Pietro: any polynomial in one variable will split; for yours, $b_1(\mu) = (\lambda + 1)^2 + 1 = (\lambda + 1 + i)(\lambda + 1 - i)$.

Comment: Per: the dimension formula appears in some of the research that led to this question, but isn't the sole basis for it.

Comment: I've manged to come up with a sketch of a proof for this; the proof goes through the fact that for any irreducible $a_i(\lambda)$ that divides $b_\mu(\lambda)$, there is some $\alpha_i$ such that for any $\gamma$ with $\langle \alpha_i, \gamma\rangle = 0$, $a_i(\lambda + \gamma) = a_i(\lambda)$, which shows that $a_i$ is divisible by $\alpha_i + k_i$ for some $k_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The positive answer to this question appears in the appendix to Sato, Shintani, and Muro's [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118782193) on b-functions (which were the source of this question in the first place).